# Извлечение коллекции в listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Теперь возник вопрос. В свойстве содержится коллекция из нескольких элементов, как поместить эти элементы в listbox?

Comment: ItemsSource пробовали?

Comment: Предлагаю решать проблему в одном вопросе. Если какой-либо ответ вам показался непонятным, просто уточните у автора.